# How to run only half of python-behave tests

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

We have two machines with the purpose to split our testing across machines to make testing faster. I would like to know of a way to tell behave to run half of the tests. I am aware of the **--tags** argument but this is too cumbersome as, when the test suite grows, so must our **--tags** argument if we wish to keep it at the halfway point. I would also need to know which of the other half of tests were not run so I can run those on the other machine.

TL;DR Is there a simple way to get behave to run, dynamically, half of the tests? (that doesn't include specifying which tests through the use of **--tags**)

And is there a way of finding the other half of tests that were not run?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not, you would have to write your own runner to do that. But that would be complex to do as trying to piece together content of two separate test runs, which are half of each other would be rather complex if any errors are to show up.

A better and faster solution will be to write a simple bash/python script that will traverse given directory for .feature files and then fire indivisdual behave process against it. Then with properly configured outputs it should be collision free in terms of outputs and if you separate your cases give you a much better boost than running half. And of course delegate that task to other machine by some means, be it bare SSH command or queues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately we are testing hardware so we can't have more than one behave process run at a time on a machine as the drivers can only handle one connection at a time. I will still use the idea of a python script to run through the .feature files though as that would be easiest.
Thank you